# Countability of the difference of two uncountable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are two uncountable subsets of $\mathbb R$ then the set $A\setminus B$

- (1) has to be uncountable
- (2) has to be countable
- (3) has to be infinite
- (4) None of the above.

Comment: Well,...what do you think, and why?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts, say substituting some specific examples like $A = \Bbb{R}, B = \Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and $A = \Bbb{R}, B = \Bbb{R}\setminus(0,1)$, etc

Answer (score 1):

It can be any. If $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(0,\frac{1}{2})$, then $A\setminus B=[\frac{1}{2},1)$ which is uncountable and hence infinite.

If $A=[0,1]$ and $B=(0,1)$, then $A\setminus B$ is finite, and hence countable.

So, if $A$ and $B$ are uncountable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then their difference $A\setminus B$ may be empty, finite, countable or uncountable. So the correct answer is (d), none of the above as it doesn't HAVE to be any of them.

Comment: I discard first and third option by taking A=B and discard second by taking A= (0,4), B=(1,2). Now I'm understand the problem completely. Thanks chetan vuppulury for the help.